# How to restrict user to a specific folder using AWS SDK for PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-sdk

I have created a script using AWS SDK for PHP that creates a folder for each customer on signup, customers will be uploading/downloading files from their own folder only.

I don't want to share access key and secret with customers as this gives full access to the bucket and all  its files and folders. Is there a way to create folder specific access keys to restrict customers only to their own folder?

So basically I am after some limited access keys, is there any workaround?

Many thanks!

Comment: Its been a while since i've deal with the AWS security but take a look onto  `Federated Users` http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingTempFederationTokenPHP.html

Comment: @forcewill I am not running script inside AWS hosting, how to make it work outside of AWS?

Comment: i can only explain in an high level what the process i had since some years passed since i worked with AWS, but basically i had the customers app communicate with my server the server asked for a temporary session in Amazon S3 with GetSessionToken/GetFederationToken methods and returned the token back to the client, the client used the token to talk directly with S3